# Set Virtualmin default website when entering by IP

Tags: centos, httpd, virtualmin

I installed Virtualmin in CentOS 7.4 and I have 1 VirtualServer configured to a domain, when I navigate with the server IP I want to target a custom website hosted in /var/www/html or wathever instead of the first vhost on the server.

My httpd.conf is default, only edited ServerName with my custom domain.
I need to setup my SSL to make some cURL calls with a custom Virtualmin API too.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is set up another virtualhost with the domain for your server (eg vpsserver.com or vps.existingdomain.com) assuming this is different from your existing website) then set this as your virtualmin default server.